# Invalid SQL statement error with refcursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle9i, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to get the results of the underlying statements. The SQL statements works without any problems. However, in order to print the results I would like to use refcursor. I get the following errors:

ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
ORA-01008: not all variables bound
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

```
VARIABLE reader refcursor;
DECLARE
  line varchar2(32767);
BEGIN
  line := 'SELECT role_id,';
  FOR n IN (SELECT name
              FROM (SELECT competence.skill_role.role_id,
                           competence.skill_label.name,
                           competence.skill_role.target_value
                      FROM competence.skill_role,
                           competence.skill_label
                     WHERE competence.skill_label.skill_id =
                           competence.skill_role.skill_id
                       AND competence.skill_label.language_id = 1)
                       matrix_result ) LOOP
    line := line || '(decode(name,''' || n.name ||
            ''',target_value)) "' || n.name || '",';
  END LOOP;
  line := RTRIM(line, ',') ||
    ' FROM (SELECT competence.skill_role.role_id,
                   competence.skill_label.name,
                   competence.skill_role.target_value
              FROM competence.skill_role, competence.skill_label
             WHERE competence.skill_label.skill_id =
                   competence.skill_role.skill_id
               AND competence.skill_label.language_id = 1) matrix_result';
--dbms_output.put_line(line);
--execute immediate line;
 OPEN :reader FOR line;
END;
/
PRINT :reader;
```

Table data

```
CREATE TABLE competence.skill_role
  (skill_id  NUMBER,
   role_id NUMBER,
   target_value NUMBER)
/
INSERT ALL 
INTO competence.skill_role VALUES (3432030, 1421866, 2)
INTO competence.skill_role VALUES (3434962, 1421866, 2)
INTO competence.skill_role VALUES (3488025, 3488804, 4)


SELECT * FROM competence.skill_role

SKILL_ID ROLE_ID     target_value
---------- -------   -----------
3432030 1421866       2
3434962 1421866       2
3488025 3488804       4


CREATE TABLE competence.skill_label
  (skill_id  NUMBER,
   name vchar2 (30))
/
INSERT ALL 
INTO competence.skill_label VALUES (3432030, 'Alueen projektipätevyys')
INTO competence.skill_label VALUES (3434962, 'Moottorin koekäyttö')
INTO competence.skill_label VALUES (3488025, 'Etähallintajärjestelmät')


SELECT * FROM arc_competence.skill_label

SKILL_ID NAME
---------- -------
3432030, Alueen projektipätevyys
3434962, Moottorin koekäyttö
3488025, Etähallintajärjestelmät
```

I would like to have the following result from the first query. From your answer (if I understood correctly), it seems that I need to run the resultant query manually to get the answer. I'd like to have the result without running the resultant query :-) I don't have the access to the client machine at the moment but I am going there now.

```
ROLE_ID     Alueen projektipätevyys  Moottorin koekäyttö    Etähallintajärjestelmät          
1421866          2                      2
3488804                                                            4
```

Comment: If you uncomment the `dbms_output.put_line` call before your `OPEN`, what is the SQL statement that it shows?

Comment: I get the result of SQL query (which is a valid SQL query itself for dynamic pivoting )

Comment: Then I'm confused.  If `line` is a valid SQL query, your code will run successfully (as I demonstrated below).  If you are getting an error, that implies that the SQL statement you're generating is not valid or that there is more to the problem that you haven't mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

If I correct your code so that it compiles

- Your `INSERT ALL` statements are missing a `SELECT`
- The `name` column in `skill_label` is defined as a `vchar2(30)` rather than a `varchar2(30)`
- Your anonymous block references a column `language_id` that your DDL does not include

the code runs without error.  If the only problem is that you want to combine the first two rows into a single row, you just need to add a `MAX` to all the columns other than `ROLE_ID` and to add a `GROUP BY role_id` to your query.

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  CREATE TABLE skill_role
  2    (skill_id  NUMBER,
  3     role_id NUMBER,
  4*    target_value NUMBER)
SQL> /

Table created.

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  INSERT ALL
  2  INTO skill_role VALUES (3432030, 1421866, 2)
  3  INTO skill_role VALUES (3434962, 1421866, 2)
  4  INTO skill_role VALUES (3488025, 3488804, 4)
  5* select * from dual
SQL> /

3 rows created.


SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  CREATE TABLE skill_label
  2    (skill_id  NUMBER,
  3*    name varchar2 (30))
SQL> /

Table created.

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  INSERT ALL
  2  INTO skill_label VALUES (3432030, 'Alueen projektipΣtevyys')
  3  INTO skill_label VALUES (3434962, 'Moottorin koekΣytt÷')
  4  INTO skill_label VALUES (3488025, 'EtΣhallintajΣrjestelmΣt')
  5* select * from dual
SQL> /

3 rows created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> variable reader refcursor;

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  DECLARE
  2    line varchar2(32767);
  3  BEGIN
  4    line := 'SELECT role_id,';
  5    FOR n IN (SELECT name
  6                FROM (SELECT skill_role.role_id,
  7                             skill_label.name,
  8                             skill_role.target_value
  9                        FROM skill_role,
 10                             skill_label
 11                       WHERE skill_label.skill_id =
 12                             skill_role.skill_id
 13                         )
 14                         matrix_result ) LOOP
 15      line := line || 'max(decode(name,''' || n.name ||
 16              ''',target_value)) "' || n.name || '",';
 17    END LOOP;
 18    line := RTRIM(line, ',') ||
 19      ' FROM (SELECT skill_role.role_id,
 20                     skill_label.name,
 21                     skill_role.target_value
 22                FROM skill_role, skill_label
 23               WHERE skill_label.skill_id =
 24                     skill_role.skill_id
 25                 ) matrix_result ' ||
 26       ' GROUP BY role_id' ;
 27    dbms_output.put_line(line);
 28    --execute immediate line;
 29    OPEN :reader FOR line;
 30* END;
 31  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print reader

   ROLE_ID Alueen projektipΣtevyys Moottorin koekΣytt÷ EtΣhallintajΣrjestelmΣt
---------- ----------------------- ------------------- -----------------------
   1421866                       2                   2
   3488804                                                                   4
```

Comment: Thanks..I've just edited my original question so show the desirable result.
(by the way, how can I add the code in my reply because now I edited my original question to add the lines for desired result.

Comment: hmmm..where is "reader" declared in your code? (from line 28)

Comment: @Jaanna - My declaration of `reader` is the same as yours.  It just appears that I forgot to include that first line in my copy and paste.  I fixed that and adjusted the code to return the results you want.